# Eclipse - different folder-/file colors per project

Tags: eclipse, explorer

I'm looking for a way to optically mark different projects in the eclipse "Project Explorer".
From time to time I have to work with several opened projects, to copy files and folders from old to new projects. (I know it is possible to compare folders.. but it is not always the best way)
So it would be really convenient to apply a different color for the main project. E.g. having displayed the folders of that project in green instead of yellow - so this would avoid copy-pasting in the wrong 'direction'.

Any ideas? Or other tips?

[image: Example Screenshot]

**Edit:**
Added image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse isnt exploded make-up-bag :D

If you have your projects unter Version-Controll, you can specify custom file/folder/project-decorators with markant Text-Labels.

Therefore see Window->Preferences->Team->...->Label Decoration